# Make div clickable, only when anchor is present in div (multiple divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Given a basic structure how can I turn a series of divs into links without turning *every* div into a link? Here's an example:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"><p>Some text with a <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a></p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>Some text without a link</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>Some text with a <a href="https://www.example.com">link</a></p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>Some text without a link</p></div>
</div>
```

And the associated jQuery I'm using to make the divs clickable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if($('.boxes p a').length){

    $(".boxes .box").click(function() {
      window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
      return false;
    });

  }

});
```

The problem I'm running into is the click function gets applied to *all* divs instead of only those with links.

The desired behavior is to only create a fully clickable div only when an anchor element is found.

For the purposes of this use case, the div (`.box`) is generated dynamically and wrapping the element in an anchor tag (`<a href="#"><div> </div></a>`) is not possible.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fu8xLg0d/

Comment: thats really a hard work, why don't you give css to 'a' tag that will perfectly look like a div without using js you will solve your purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you add event listeners on all the `.boxes .box` classes, which are all your divs.

Just add something like :

```
$(".boxes .box").has('a')...
```

to narrow it to those only containing an `a` element

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4os541/12)

Comment: thank you! I originally explored .has(), but I had set it in conjunction with .length() which resulted in my original error.

Answer (score 0):

use `.parent` to solve your purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if($('.boxes p a').length){

    $("a").parent().parent().click(function() {
      window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
      return false;
    });

  }

});
```

But yes, it can even create a problem so i will say to give  a class to your link and then call its parent... :)

Comment: I would have normally added a class to the anchor or even wrapped the card in an anchor, but in this particular instance the card is generated dynamically with user generated content. This most straightforward option which required as little end user input as possible was the JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Plotisateur just beat me by a minute or two! :P

```
if($('.boxes p a').length){
    $(".boxes .box").has('a').click(function() {
      window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
      return false;
});
```

Here's the code anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/fu8xLg0d/1/

Comment: Maybe three haha ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can try this.

  $(document).ready(function() {
  var anchorbox =$(".boxes p a");
  if(anchorbox.length>0){
    $(anchorbox).parent().click(function() {
    window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
     return false;
    }); 
  }
 });
```

Comment: `anchorbox` is a collection/arraylist, I dont think it will have `parent` method

Answer (score 0):

This little change, helps you to resolve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if($('.boxes p a').length){

$(".boxes .box").click(function() {

if ($(this).children('p').children('a').length) {

    window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
return false;
}

});

}

});
```

the difference from your code is, additionally add a checking

```
if ($(this).children('p').children('a').length) {

    window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> div (.box) is generated dynamically.

Delegate the click event from the `body` to the target div and on `click` on the element check if it has anchor tag. For adding the pointer icon create a separate function which will add the icon to the div only if it has an anchor tag as child

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // separate function to add pointer only if a is present
  addClassToElem();
  $("body").on('click', '.box', function() {
    if ($(this).find('a').length) {

      window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
      return false;
    }

  })
});

function addClassToElem() {
  $('.box a').each(function(a, b) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('linkIcon')
  })

}
```

```css
.linkIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text with a <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text without a link</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text with a <a href="https://www.example.com">link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text without a link</p>
  </div>
</div>
```